# Is there a Uno-Platform head for a WinUI(xaml) and net7.0 desktop linux based app?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, debian, uno-platform

These are all the heads created when you run the following general command to create a new uno app "MyApp":

```
dotnet new unoapp -o MyApp --vscode

MyApp
MyApp.Base
MyApp.Mobile
MyApp.Server
MyApp.Skia.Gtk
MyApp.Skia.Linux.FrameBuffer
MyApp.Skia.WPF
MyApp.Wasm
MyApp.Windows
```

I want to try a UWP, now WinUI3 style app for desktop linux. The only "head" that I see with a similar `App.xaml.cs` structure is the `MyApp.Base` "head". The 'MyApp' head above is the shared code part right?

Also,when I run the following creating the app:

```
dotnet new unoapp -o MyApp -mobile=false --skia-wpf=false --skia-linux-fb=false --skia-gtk=false -wasm=false --vscode
```

I get the following heads:

```
MyApp
MyApp.Base
MyApp.Skia.WPF
MyApp.Windows
```

But in my launch.json I have these two configuration sets:

```
"name": "Debug (Chrome, WebAssembly)",
"name": "Skia.GTK (Debug)",
```

What am I missing?

I don't see an auto `Add Configuration` option for linux with a xaml window UI?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select linux when creating a new project.
[image]

Screenshot taken from https://platform.uno/docs/articles/getting-started-tutorial-1.html.

If you do it from `dotnet new`, don't remove the linux options.
Remove the following arguments from your command `--skia-linux-fb=false --skia-gtk=false`.

About the solution structure for code sharing, know that the project template recently changed to move away from [Shared Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows). The new structure uses a multi-targeted library. Here's the blog post about it: https://platform.uno/blog/uno-platform-4-7-new-project-template-performance-improvements-and-more/

Comment: Thanks @Batesias, I will read through that blog now...    though - do you know if that combo is possible - xaml/WinUI3 + linux(vSCode)

Comment: I've never tried Linux but it should work. I'm currently using the WinUI3 xaml for iOS and Android and it works :)

Comment: That gives some good info - though they do not show or mention MyApp.Base... do you know what the function is of that?  You build your app in MyApp, not MyApp.Base?

Comment: I can't find clear documentation about that new structure at the moment. However, you can reach out for support directly on [GitHub or Discord](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/faq.html#where-can-i-get-support)

Comment: @Batesias , any chance you have some sample code / app that I can try it on Linux?  Still struggling...